# How do i align my Thumb Nail images horizontally in CSS?

Tags: css, image, html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align a set of images horizontally within a div tag and then display a horizontal scroll bar when the images exceed the length of the div tag. I am relatively new to CSS and have tried everything I can think of. The below code displays my images vertically!!!

Thank you very much for any help.

Inside the body tag:

```
<div id="TNBox">
<ul class="imagelist">
    <li>
        <img id="tnimage1" src="images/tn-images/Rio-Street-Art-TN01.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="tnimage2" src="images/tn-images/Rio-Street-Art-TN02.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="tnimage3" src="images/tn-images/Rio-Street-Art-TN03.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="tnimage4" src="images/tn-images/Rio-Street-Art-TN04.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="tnimage5" src="images/tn-images/Rio-Street-Art-TN05.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>



And the CSS:

#TNBox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 88px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 320px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.imagelist {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please reword your question title - "TN" usually stands for Tennessee, not "thumbnail".

Comment: Also, please convert your question into a jsFiddle. visit jsfiddle.com and enter your code, hit Share, and post the generated link.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have done this now. I am new to forums (and CSS). I will do this in any future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to fiddle.  I also changed the image urls to point to something that exists

http://jsfiddle.net/GVdMz/2/

Here is what I added:

To get the images to display horizontally

```
.imagelist li{
  display: inline;
}
```

And this will make a horizontal scroll appear if the images extend past the width of #TNBox

```
#TNBox{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#TNBox{
    width: 500px;
    height: 88px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 320px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.imagelist{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.imagelist li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Preview >>** *[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EaffC/2/) (I have styled images too)*

Comment: madhushankarox, Thank you very much for your help. My thunbnails are aligned horizontally!